# Using an OR condition in TaffyDB with "lte" and "gte"

Tags: javascript, taffydb

I have data in taffy DB that look like this. Data points can be blank:

```
{"first_name":"Sam", "last_name": "Andrew", "age":26 ... }
{"first_name":"Jane", "last_name": "Doe", "age": 19 ... } 
{"first_name":"John", "last_name": "Deer", "age":51 ... }
.
.
.
```

If i need all the rows where the first name is either "John" or "Jane", the age is between 40 and 60, the query would be:

```
{
    "name":["John","Jane"], 
    "age":{"lte":60,"gte":40}
}
```

Now if I add the condition that the age can be less than 20 as well, I am unable to write a query for that.

I have tried this but it does not work:

```
{
    "name":["John","Jane"], 
    "age":[{"lte":60,"gte":40},{"lte":20}]
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It helps to break this down into an age-related `or` statement and the Name-and-Age `and` statement.

You want the Name condition *and* the Age condition (which contains its own `or`)

A standard `and` statement is normally written *(in pseudocode)* as:

```
db({name_condition, age_condition})
```

but can also be written as

```
db({name_condition},{age_condition})
```

---

This second notation is needed to accomplish the compound condition you're looking for.

Because your entire Age condition is effectively one simple `or` statement, you'd put it in an array.

```
[
  {age:{"lte":20}},
  {age:{"gte":40,"lte":60}}
]
```

*Either* age is less than than 20 *or* age is between 40 and 60.

The Name condition is straightforward

```
{first_name:["John","Jane"]}
```

Put the two objects together into an `and` statement like this:

```
db({first_name:["John","Jane"]},[{age:{"lte":20}},{age:{"gte":40,"lte":60}}])
```